# Why do only certain UPC codes work in this code

Tags: python, web-scraping, barcode

In this code, I search through a site to retrieve data about a specific UPC code. But, the problem is that this code only works for certain URLs. For example an error is returned if the URL is "627386004004", but it works if the URL is "20313447006". Why does this only work certain UPC's. However, if I simply just put the 2 URLs in the browser they both return a valid page.

https://www.realcanadiansuperstore.ca/search/1522603193415/page/~item/20313447006/~sort/recommended/~selected/true

https://www.realcanadiansuperstore.ca/search/1522603193415/page/~item/627386004004/~sort/recommended/~selected/true

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import time
from lxml import html

upc = '627386004004'
base_url = 'https://www.realcanadiansuperstore.ca'

# Get search results
now = round(time.time())
url = base_url + 
f'/search/{now}/page/~item/{upc}/~sort/recommended/~selected/true'
response = requests.get(url)
body = response.text

# Parse search results
tree = html.fromstring(body)
if not len(tree.xpath('//div[@class="content-tile-list"]/div')) == 1:
    raise Exception('Invalid number of results')
url = base_url + tree.xpath('//div[@class="content-tile-list"]/div/div/div/div[@class="product-info"]/div/a/@href')[0]

# Get product page
res = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(res.text)
name = " ".join(tree.xpath('//h1[@class="product-name"]/text()')[1].split())

print(name)
```

The error returned is the exception, which I tested for in the code.

`Exception: Invalid number of results`

If I am missing any detail, or doing something wrong please let me know :)

EDIT: Using Python 3.6

Comment: Why do you think the browser wouldn't show a valid page even if an error code is returned?

Comment: Because I inspected what the returned DOM was when an error was showed. Moreover, I am trying to retrieve the name, and with those "invalid" URL, the name is not returned.

Comment: When you say "an error is returned", what does that mean? That `response.statuscode` a 404? That you get an exception from `requests`? (If so, paste the exception here.) That you get a page back but it doesn't have what you expect on it? (If so, explain which of your xpath searches failed and why you expected it to succeed.)

Comment: When I try these URLs, I get a perfectly valid "nothing found" page for the second one, which doesn't have the `div`s you're looking for in the browser. But if you wait long enough on that page, it seems to load their front page or something, which _does_ have some of them. Maybe that's what's confusing you?

Comment: @abarnert The error I get is the exception I am testing for. I included it in the description. I expect it the xpath's to work because in the original page source those xpath's make sense. Moreover, the xpath's work perfectly find for the URL "20313447006". Thus, it should work for other URLs as well.

Comment: @abarnert Are you sure you get a "nothing found", because the webpage loads a result for me. Could the problem be something related to the location?

Comment: `We were unable to find results for "627386004004"` That's what I get with curl, or with a browser with location services blocked. I don't know what I'd get if I allowed it to request my location, but whatever it is, that would obviously only affect what the JS does to the page after it's loaded, so that won't help you.

Comment: They might be using IP-driven server-side geolocation _and_ location services-driven client-side geolocation, of course. A site whose "not found" is not a 404 but instead a search page that takes you somewhere else before you can enter a search, I wouldn't be surprised if they threw in every technology that exists…

Comment: @abarnert Ahhh, yes you are right. I was working on the same problem. Figured out once I deleted cookies and cache, I was getting an error too.

Comment: So maybe your browser had an old version of the page in the cache that did have a `//div[@class="content-tile-list"]/div'`, but the current (error) page doesn't? If so, there's really no question here, so you can close or delete it.

Comment: A UPC-A code contains a Number Systems digit, followed by a 5 digit manufacturing code, followed by a 5 digit product id code followed by a check digit which is usually calculated when printing. I notice the two numbers you give are different lengths. Is it possible the number that is not working is too long?